# Check if Array has identical Entries

Tags: php

I got an array, with alot of entries, like:

```
$array = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'abc'];
```

Now I wanna check, if there are identical entries in this array.
For example there is 'abc' twice in this array.
When I found identical entries, I wanna filter them out.

Whats the best way to do that  **without**  MySQL?

I could just check

```
if($array[0] == $array[1])
etc
```

but that would be horrible amount of work, and some bad programming i guess.

Greetings

Comment: array_unique() perhaps

Comment: Do you want to filter every occurrence of duplicates out so they don't appear at all, or simply to leave one

Comment: Nevermind, Fluffeh already answered my question!:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use array_unqique: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.

Note that keys are preserved. array_unique() sorts the values treated as string at first, then will keep the first key encountered for every value, and ignore all following keys. It does not mean that the key of the first related value from the unsorted array will be kept.

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

Comment: yupp, no function can do better than array_unique() of your problem.. :)